# Does receiving a 'Nice' rating from passersby/accquaintances do anything?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

One of the features of the Player Search System (PSS) is the ability to give or receive a 'Nice' rating.

If you get one, all it seems to do is play a sound and shoot some stars across the bottom screen, whilst saying something like "Sally said Nice!".

But does it have any tangible benefits in-game? Or is it purely aesthetic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you look at your profile you can see the amount of 'Nice' ratings you have received. Apart from that, it does nothing.